# Condition for product of increasing and decreasing functions to be quasiconcave?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is there any condition for product of increasing and decreasing functions to be quasiconcave?

More specifically, I am having in mind a condition for $F(x)\cdot(1-G(x))$ to be quasi concave where $F$ and $G$ are CDFs. Thank you in advance

Comment: Furthermore, is there any condition such that both F(x)*(1-G(x)) and G(x)*(1-F(x)) are quasi concave?

Comment: Nothing nontrivial, I'm afraid. If $|F''|$ is small compared to $F'$, and similarly for $G$, you may be able to get $F(1-G)$ to be concave.

Comment: Thank you for a reply, Human. Indeed, the problem is very difficult. One trivial assumption to ensure concavity would be to assume F''=0=G'' in which case we always have a negative second derivative for the product, a too strong assumption  for me to impose.